# FSharp Computation Expression: Cannot reference binding value in custom operation

Tags: f#, computation-expression

I am trying to make a builder using FSharp Computation Expression, but get error FS0039:

```fsharp
type UpdatebBuilder() =
    member this.Yield (x) = x
    member this.Return (x) = x
    member this.Bind (x, cont) = cont(x)
    member this.Quote (x) = x
    member this.For (x, a) = x

    [<CustomOperation("set", MaintainsVariableSpace =true,AllowIntoPattern=true)>] 
    member this.Set (x, a, b) = x

let update = UpdatebBuilder()

let testUpdate () =
    update {
        for x in [| 1; 2 ; 3|] do
        set x 123  // Compile Error FS0039: The value or constructor 'x' is not defined.
    }
```

What I want to implement is something like query expression:

```
query {
    for x in collection do
    where x = 2 // Why no FS0039 error here?
    select x
}
```

Also tried `MaintainsVariableSpaceUsingBind=true`, and get same error. What should I do to make it compile?

Answer (score 2):

To me it looks like you are trying to define a State monad and implementing the Set operation as a custom operation.

I will admit I never fully got my head around custom operations in F# (and I used F# alot). IMHO it feels like custom operations had one purpose; enable a LINQ like syntax in F#. As time goes in it seems few C# developers are using the LINQ like syntax (ie `from x where y select z`) and few F# developers are using the `query` computation expression. I have no data here but just goes from example code I see.

This could explain why the documentation on custom operations are often succinct and hard to grasp. What does this even mean? `MaintainsVariableSpaceUsingBind: Indicates if the custom operation maintains the variable space of the query or computation expression through the use of a bind operation.`

Anyway, so in order to learn a bit more about custom operations I tried to implement the state monad with a custom operation for `set` and I got a bit farther but ran into a problem which I think is an intentional limitation of the compiler. Still thought I share it with the hope that it helps OP get a bit further.

I chose this definition for `State<_>`:

```
type [<Struct>] State<'T> = S of (Map<string, obj> -> 'T*Map<string, obj>)
```

`State<_>` is a function that given a global state (a map) produces a value (that could derive from the global state but not necessarily) and a potentially updated global state.

`return` or `value` as I tend to call it as `return` is an F# keyword is easy to define as we just return v and the non-updated global state:

```
let value v         = S <| fun m -> v, m
```

`bind` is useful to bind several state computations together. First run `t` on the global state and from the returned value create the second computation and run the updated global state through it:

```
let bind  uf (S t)  = S <| fun m -> 
  let tv, tm  = t m
  let (S u)   = uf tv
  u tm
```

`get` and `set` are used to interact with the global state:

```
let get k : State<'T option> = S <| fun m ->
  match m |> Map.tryFind k with
  | Some (:? 'T as v) -> Some v, m
  | _                 -> None, m

let set k v = S <| fun m ->
  let m = m |> Map.add k (box v)
  (), m
```

I created some other methods as well but in the end the builder was created like this:

```
type Builder() =
  class
    member x.Bind       (t, uf) = bind    uf t
    member x.Combine    (t, u)  = combine u  t
    member x.Delay      tf      = delay   tf
    member x.For        (s, tf) = forEach s  tf
    member x.Return     v       = value   v
    member x.ReturnFrom t       = t             : State<'T>
    member x.Yield      v       = value   v
    member x.Zero ()            = value   ()

    [<CustomOperation("set", MaintainsVariableSpaceUsingBind = true)>] 
    member x.Set (s, k, v)      = s |> combine (set k v)
  end
```

I used `MaintainsVariableSpaceUsingBind` because otherwise it doesn't see `v`. `MaintainsVariableSpace` yields strange errors asking for `seq` types which I vaguely suspect is an optimization for computations based around `seq`. Checking the generated code is seems to do the right thing in that it binds the custom operations together using my bind function in the proper order.

I am now ready to do define a `state` computation

```
state {
  // Works fine
  set "key" -1
  for v in 0..2 do
    // Won't work because: FS3086: A custom operation may not be used in conjunction with 'use', 'try/with', 'try/finally', 'if/then/else' or 'match' operators within this computation expression
    set "hello" v
  return! State.get "key"
}
```

Unfortunately the compiler stops me from using custom ops in conditional operations like `if`, `try` and also `for` (even though it's not in the list it's conditional in some sense). This seems to be an intentional limitation. It's possible to workaround it but it feels meh

```
state {
  set "key" -1
  for v in 0..2 do
    // Meh
    do! state { set "key" v }
  return! State.get "key"
}
```

IMHO I prefer just using normal `do!/let!` over custom operations:

```
state {
  for v in 0..2 do
    do! State.set "key" v
  return! State.get "key"
}
```

So not really a proper answer to the question from OP but perhaps it can help you get a bit further?

Full source code:

```
type [<Struct>] State<'T> = S of (Map<string, obj> -> 'T*Map<string, obj>)

module State =
  let value v         = S <| fun m -> v, m

  let bind  uf (S t)  = S <| fun m -> 
    let tv, tm  = t m
    let (S u)   = uf tv
    u tm

  let combine u (S t) = S <| fun m -> 
    let _, tm   = t m
    let (S u)   = u
    u tm

  let delay tf  = S <| fun m -> 
    let (S t) = tf ()
    t m

  let forEach s tf  = S <| fun m -> 
    let mutable a = m
    for v in s do
      let (S t)   = tf v
      let (), tm  = t m
      a <- tm
    (), a

  let get k : State<'T option> = S <| fun m ->
    match m |> Map.tryFind k with
    | Some (:? 'T as v) -> Some v, m
    | _                 -> None, m

  let set k v = S <| fun m ->
    let m = m |> Map.add k (box v)
    (), m

  let run (S t) m = t m

  type Builder() =
    class
      member x.Bind       (t, uf) = bind    uf t
      member x.Combine    (t, u)  = combine u  t
      member x.Delay      tf      = delay   tf
      member x.For        (s, tf) = forEach s  tf
      member x.Return     v       = value   v
      member x.ReturnFrom t       = t             : State<'T>
      member x.Yield      v       = value   v
      member x.Zero ()            = value   ()

      [<CustomOperation("set", MaintainsVariableSpaceUsingBind = true)>] 
      member x.Set (s, k, v)      = s |> combine (set k v)
    end
let state = State.Builder ()

let testUpdate () =
  state {
    // Works fine
    set "key" -1
    for v in 0..2 do
      // Won't work because: FS3086: A custom operation may not be used in conjunction with 'use', 'try/with', 'try/finally', 'if/then/else' or 'match' operators within this computation expression
      // set "hello" v
      // Workaround but kind of meh
      // do! state { set "key" v }
      // Better IMHO
      do! State.set "key" v
    return! State.get "key"
  }

[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv =
  let tv, tm = State.run (testUpdate ()) Map.empty
  printfn "v:%A" tv
  printfn "m:%A" tm
  0
```

Comment: Ok, the key point is `[<ProjectionParameter>]` attribute. I have to add this attribute to the second parameter of `set` method to make it compiles. Your answer also helps alot, thank you!